# how can i get last value from a Observable?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

i try to get last value from a observable.
the example code is

```js
// RxJS v6+
import { lastValueFrom, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { scan } from 'rxjs/operators';

async function main() {
  const subject = new Subject();

  const example = subject.pipe(
    scan((acc, curr) => {
      return Object.assign({}, acc, curr);
    }, {}),
  );
  const subscribe = example.subscribe((val) =>
    console.log('Accumulated object:', val),
  );
  subject.next({ name: 'Joe' });
  subject.next({ age: 30 });
  subject.next({ favoriteLanguage: 'JavaScript' });

  console.log('+++++++++++++');
  const resp = await lastValueFrom(example);
  console.log(resp);
  console.log('end');
}

main()
  .catch((e) => {
    console.error(e);
  })
  .finally(async () => {
    console.log('final');
  });
```

the output is

```bash
➜  npns-service git:(mr/master/658) ✗ ts-node prisma/test.ts
Accumulated object: { name: 'Joe' }
Accumulated object: { name: 'Joe', age: 30 }
Accumulated object: { name: 'Joe', age: 30, favoriteLanguage: 'JavaScript' }
+++++++++++++
```

i can't got the resp output message.

how can i got the resp value from example Observable?

Comment: The observable is never completed, so there is never a _last_ (i.e. final, not latest) value to return from `lastValueFrom`! It keeps waiting for the observable to get completed, which never happens, so your log statement is never reached.

Comment: thanks. so how can i got a newest value from a observable?

Answer (score 1):

Update your code to complete your observable:

```ts
setTimeout(() => { // setTimeout is just a simple way to use JS's event loop
    subject.next({ name: 'Joe' });
    subject.next({ age: 30 });
    subject.next({ favoriteLanguage: 'JavaScript' });
    subject.complete(); // signal that our observable is done emitting
    // subject.next(something) here would do 
    // nothing, the observable is complete 
}, 0);

console.log('+++++++++++++');
const resp = await lastValueFrom(example);
console.log(resp);
console.log('end');
```

---

If you don't complete an observable, as far as your run-time is aware it may still emit something else in a minute, 5 hours, next year - who knows? There must be some condition that triggers completion.

**A quick aside:** I threw the code that emits on your subject into the event loop so that the code that follows can `await` it. Otherwise your subject would complete synchronously before that code was ever run.

### Update 1: how can i got a newest value from a observable?

Make `example` an observable that remembers (buffers) the last emission. Then just use `take(1)` to read the buffered value.

```ts
const subject = new Subject();

const example = subject.pipe(
    scan((acc, curr) => Object.assign({}, acc, curr), {}),
    shareReplay(1)
);
example.subscribe(val =>
    console.log('Accumulated object:', val)
);

subject.next({ name: 'Joe' });
subject.next({ age: 30 });
subject.next({ favoriteLanguage: 'JavaScript' });

console.log('+++++++++++++');
const resp = await lastValueFrom(example.pipe(take(1));
console.log(resp);
console.log('end');
```

Comment: thanks. so  how can i got a newest value from a observable?

Comment: @kula Updated with a suggestion